# What is the best way to use LESS with Espresso 2?

Tags: css, less, macrabbit-espresso

I recently started to use LESS for my CSS coding and also upgraded from CSSEdit to the recent Espresso 2 app. Is there a good LESS sugar out there for Espresso 2?

Im highly addicted to using the x-ray feature in Espresso and the inspector and I need my fix soon :)

Comment: I decided to not use any of the Espresso sugars that I've come across, simply because none of them automatically indent the code when nesting rules, a feature of LESS I use extensively. So I opted for merely adding 'less' to the list of css-compatible languages. Not bug free at all, but does the job. My write-up of how to do it here: http://deliciouslyweird.com/2013/04/getting-support-for-less-in-espresso/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/cellfusion/LESS.sugar

looks like it will do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I was using some other Sugar I found that was not working well. This one looks like the best one to use.

Comment: syntax highlighting works well, navigation bar just shows folders however

Answer (score 2):

The most up to date one is here

https://github.com/mkoistinen/LESS.sugar

Comment: This is much less buggy than the version originally posted.

Comment: more buggy for me, lose the entire navigation bar much of the time

Comment: They're kind of both semi-useless. All you get is syntax coloring. What you really want is CSS-editor support (which probably requires Expresso's internals to change).

Answer (score 0):

This is the most recent version: https://github.com/alexanderweiss/LESS.sugar

Probably also most stable, but I used it much just yet.